# Getting value from an attribute from a class inside another class but I'm getting nullPointerException

Tags: java, json, spring, object, attributes

I'm getting the values ​​from another repository fine but when I try to set the values I'm getting nullPointerException

Here I got the object whit the class ResumenCreditosResponse

```
final String jsonResponse = this.customHttpClient.execute(method);
        BaseResponse<ResumenCreditosResponse> respuesta = parseJson(jsonResponse, ResumenCreditosResponse.class);
```

And here is where I am trying to set the value from the attribute

```
resultCredit.setCodigoOficina(respuesta.getBody().getRespuesta().getCodigoSucursal());
```

With the evaluation tool from IntelliJ, I am getting the correct value
[image: correct value]

But when I run the program I am getting this error
[image]

respuesta.getBody() is a ResumenCreditosResponse Object
ResumenCreditosResponse:

```
public class ResumenCreditosResponse {
 private String codigoRespuesta;
 private String glosaRespuesta;
 private Respuesta respuesta;
...
Constructors
Getters and Setters
...
public class Respuesta {
//attributes -------------
private String codigoSucursal;
//attributes -------------
...
public String getCodigoSucursal() {
        return codigoSucursal;
    }

    public void setCodigoSucursal(String codigoSucursal) {
        this.codigoSucursal = codigoSucursal;
    }
}
```

I've been trying to get the value but I'm still getting just the error

Comment: Is `resultCredit` instantiated?

Comment: yep in the beginning
ConsumerCreditData resultCredit = null;

Comment: Well therein lies your NPE